# Calling OpenReadStream of an IFormFile multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to have the stream of the file in 2 different locations. In the code the `IFormFile` is already passed as parameter in the 2 methods. I thought of either modifying the methods and calling the `OpenReadStream` in the beginning and pass the stream as param or calling OpenReadStream separately.

I inspected the dissasembled code and `OpenReadStream` does this:

```
return new ReferenceReadStream(_baseStream, _baseStreamOffset, Length);
```

and the ReferenceReadStream class does this in the constructor:

```
public ReferenceReadStream(Stream inner, long offset, long length)
{
    if (inner == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("inner");
    }
    _inner = inner;
    _innerOffset = offset;
    _length = length;
    _inner.Position = offset;
}
```

In my understanding the base stream is the same and it doesn't matter calling `OpenReadStream` multiple times.

What worries me is if I'll run into problems when I start using Seek method.

Does anyone know what's the correct usage of `OpenReadStream` in this senario?

Comment: do you meet any error? I mean you may follow your idea to test your code and if it worked well, then we don't have issue here..

Comment: @TinyWang Yeah I did a test indeed and it's not safe. I'll post an answer later for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's not safe to call `OpenReadStream`  multiple times.

When `Read` method is called, it calls this method:

```
private void VerifyPosition()
    {
        if (_inner.Position == _innerOffset + _position)
        {
            return;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The inner stream position has changed unexpectedly.");
    }
```

I was able to trigger this exception with the following code:

```
var s = file.OpenReadStream();
s.Seek(10, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var b = new byte[2];
var c = s.Read(b);
var s2 = file.OpenReadStream();
c = s.Read(b);
```